# Ice climbing top rope with joined roped

Tags: safety, ropes, top-roping, ice-climbing

Are there any safety concerns connecting two ropes (40 and 50 m) with 2 double fisherman knots and then installing an anchor with 2 carabiners connecting the anchor to the rope for top-roping?

Let's say the ropes have more or less the same diameter (8.9 and 9.2 mm)

Comment: The way SE is supposed to work is that we curate a body of questions that are useful to other people, and we don't duplicate questions that have already been asked. This question has already been asked and answered, and its idiosyncratic details are of no interest to other people.

Answer (score 0):

Strength wise I think this would be fine.  However, be sure the belayer (and the knot) is on longer strand so the knot doesn’t hit the belay device before the climber gets to the top of the pitch.  Be very careful if you decide to rap down from the anchor.  Much easier to misjudge and rap off the end with two unequal length strands. Probably not an issue since you’re top roping but be aware.

Comment: Well this question is already closed but anyway... The knot and belayer should definitely be on the shorter strand. Otherwise the knot will get stuck in the anchor after a few meters.

Comment: Dynamic climbing ropes have to pass the UIAA-101 standard, which for a single ① rope, defines a maximum of 10% elongation on a static load. With 100m of rope in your set up that means it's feasible to take a ground fall from 10m up, even if there is no slack in the system. This is mentioned in the answers of the linked questions above but as it's a key safety point, I thought it worthwhile to add a comment here.